# Adding an 'item' using the 'container method' - getting exception back

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to add an item to content service, for a logged in user, using *addItemForContentService1* . Prior to calling this API method I'm calling *getLoginFormForContentService* to get the login form for the specific content service. To the best of my knowledge, I've filled the data as required, taking all the fields from the form retrieved earlier, putting them into "credentialFields", only adding an attribute 'value' with the needed value (username / password), as provided by the user (my user/customer) for each field. Also, I've set the other fields in the input JSON as documented in the API reference.

The content service I work on is ETrade, content service id=24 (because I have a real account there that I can use).

Here are the POST parameters are captured using php's curl CURLOPT_VERBOSE option:

> cobSessionToken=08062013_0%3A25553263f0443831be2f0c75dad28bc57896d59ac4aec35cf20‌​43ef186a65d2e726cd78d299d1b69cf06f64c606d7f89b2a9b6118ce24d9b438bdd70d24e82b1&use‌​rSessionToken=08062013_0%3Aec610a637dc6e59bd76214c3089e2459bf6b55f42b14d11dd836e3‌​59e2e8acd8e9f524e5ae50f21a0274c4e82a25f2f8ad799a8519d6947751dbab64fe3a4dea&conten‌​tServiceId=24&shareCredentialsWithinSite=true&startRefreshItemOnAddition=true&cre‌​dentialFields%5BenclosedType%5D=com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle&credentialField‌​s%5B0%5D%5BvalueIdentifier%5D=LOGIN&credentialFields%5B0%5D%5BvalueMask%5D=LOGIN_‌​FIELD&credentialFields%5B0%5D%5BfieldType%5D%5BtypeName%5D=IF_LOGIN&credentialFields%5‌​B0%5D%5Bsize%5D=20&credentialFields%5B0%5D%5Bmaxlength%5D=40&credentialFields%5B0‌​%5D%5Bname%5D=LOGIN&credentialFields%5B0%5D%5BdisplayName%5D=User+ID&credentialFi‌​elds%5B0%5D%5BisEditable%5D=1&credentialFields%5B0%5D%5BisOptional%5D=0&credentia‌​lFields%5B0%5D%5BisEscaped%5D=0&credentialFields%5B0%5D%5BhelpText%5D=4736&creden‌​tialFields%5B0%5D%5BisOptionalMFA%5D=0&credentialFields%5B0%5D%5BisMFA%5D=0&crede‌​ntialFields%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=XXX&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5BvalueIdentifier%5D=PASSWORD&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5B‌​valueMask%5D=LOGIN_FIELD&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5BfieldType%5D%5BtypeName%5D=IF_‌​PASSWORD&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5Bsize%5D=20&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5Bmaxlength‌​%5D=40&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=PASSWORD&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5Bdispl‌​ayName%5D=Password&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5BisEditable%5D=1&credentialFields%5B1‌​%5D%5BisOptional%5D=0&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5BisEscaped%5D=0&credentialFields%5‌​B1%5D%5BhelpText%5D=12023&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5BisOptionalMFA%5D=0&credential‌​Fields%5B1%5D%5BisMFA%5D=0&credentialFields%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=XXXX

I keep getting back an error:

> Unknown Exception Occurred
>
> reference code = _4c956ae5-bf4f-4d5a-801a-6abe752705d8
>
> message = argument type mismatch
>
> detailed value = Technical Difficulty Processing Request

I can't seem to find the reason for the problem. Can anyone assist?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the request you are sending for addItemForContentService1(removing/masking credential's value)?

Comment: I'll provide the information as a comment on the answer posted below. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a request for Etrade which will work. Pass in the right credentials

```
  "cobSessionToken": "xxxxx"
  "userSessionToken": "xxxxxxx"
  "contentServiceId": "24"
  "credentialFields.enclosedType": "com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle"
  "shareCredentialsWithinSite": "true"
  "startRefreshItemOnAddition": "false"
  "credentialFields[0].displayName": "User ID"
  "credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName": "IF_LOGIN"
  "credentialFields[0].helpText": "4736"
  "credentialFields[0].maxlength": 40
  "credentialFields[0].name": "LOGIN"
  "credentialFields[0].size": 20
  "credentialFields[0].value": "xxxx"
  "credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier": "LOGIN"
  "credentialFields[0].valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD"
  "credentialFields[0].isEditable": true
  "credentialFields[1].displayName": "Password"
  "credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName": "IF_PASSWORD"
  "credentialFields[1].helpText": "12023"
  "credentialFields[1].maxlength": 40
  "credentialFields[1].name": "PASSWORD"
  "credentialFields[1].size": 20
  "credentialFields[1].value": "xxxxx"
  "credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier": "PASSWORD"
  "credentialFields[1].valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD"
  "credentialFields[1].isEditable": true
  "credentialFields[2].displayName": "Login with security device OR password"
  "credentialFields[2].fieldType.typeName": "OPTIONS"
  "credentialFields[2].helpText": "159365"
  "credentialFields[2].maxlength": 40
  "credentialFields[2].name": "OP_OPTION"
  "credentialFields[2].size": 20
  "credentialFields[2].value": "xxxxxx"
  "credentialFields[2].valueIdentifier": "OP_OPTION"
  "credentialFields[2].valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD"
  "credentialFields[2].isEditable": true
```

Please note that credentialFields[2] is an optional field and hence you can choose not to pass it.

Also please make sure to follow the [refresh flow](http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Account) after this API call.

Comment: Basically I'm posting as you exampled above but I suspect that the devil is in the details:
(1) I'm posting the **full** login form as previously retrieved by running *getLoginFormForContentService*. This includes other fields for every 'credentialField' not included in your example, namely isOptional, isEscaped, isOptionalMFA and isMFA (I possibly missed some). I hope that this not "irritates" server side. Why those fields are even needed in the first place? It seems logic that it would only need sessions (cobrand + user), service id, username + password.
(comment max length reached...)

Comment: (2) Below is the complete log of the parameters posted. I'm using your PHP sample code (the probably older of the two sample application found on your website, the one NOT using the 'slim' framework (why do I need to learn a framework just to read and fully understand your sample application?...). In your sample app there's a simple REST client which I used (its post method, to be more precise). The code uses the following statement to add the parameters (php array) on the curl object: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters));

Comment: (3) Continuing from above, I've also added a CURLOPT_VERBOSE definition to curl and the resulting info written to the log file showed the following list of POST parameters passed on the request: oops, canot post this long in a comment. I'll split it to several comments... :-(

Comment: I can see that the parameters are not passed in a right way cre‌​dentialFields[enclosedType] or credentialFields[0][valueMask] these should be passed as cre‌​dentialFields.enclosedType and cre‌​dentialFields[0].valueMask similar to my request posted in the answer. This is how Yodlee will accept the parameters.

Comment: A few more things: I didn't pass the complete response from 'get login form' but rather only the credential fields retrieved from it - those are passed as is. But, with your feedback I check every field if its "isOptional" and if so I skip it and do NOT pass it to the *addItemForContentService1*. Lastly, with your example I've trimmed all the fields that are not included in your example. Still the same result. Is the fact that my account is "trial" (only sandbox) could be related? I am trying to add a real account on ETrade to a test user in my sandbox.

Comment: I assumed that we are working in JSON format - both ways. You mean that I need to pass the parameter exactly as you showed? (which is NOT a valid JSON formatting)

Comment: Actually, my syntax isn't JSON either but in any case I'm using the code showed in your sample application(!...) which just sends the parameters as POST parameters. Shall I do it differently?

Comment: Yodlee's REST API returns the response in JSON but it doesn't accept the parameters in JSON. Hence you will have to send them as POST parameters.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it and report. A natural following question: can I use the recipe above for **all non MFA** service providers? (meaning using the exact set of fields in the given format, just with different credentials values and content service id).

Comment: No, you need to use the login form values from getLoginFormForContentService API , because the field names and display name changes depending on the bank sites.

Comment: I see, but can I loop on the closed set of fields you detailed above in your original reply? I mean, otherwise, I need to know in advance every banking site my users will want to connect... . On the other hand, if I just need to provide the values **for each of the defined fields you originally mentioned**, that's fine. I'll loop on them and take their values from 'get login form' output. Can I do that? (I hope I'm clear)

Comment: Hey Boaz, it would be great if you can just remove the request fields from comment and edit your question to include it.

Comment: Shreyans - why in the first place are the form details needed? IMHO, all that is required on your end when a request to add a new item are: cob session, user session, content service id, username, password, and possibly other form-required field, but only their **values**. Why is the form **definition** required anyway? "Legacy" API and backward compatibility? (my hunch... ;-) )

Comment: Well - it worked. I've copied the code snippet suggested above, modified it where needed to make it more generic and violla - item created successfully! Thanks!